# findChild never displays textBrowser

Tags: c++, qt

I trying to display some text to a textbrowser via: FindChild and it never displays it in the textbrowswer any help would be helpfull..

Here is my mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

    namespace Ui
    {
        class MainWindow;
        class TestWindow;
    }

    class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
    {
        Q_OBJECT

    public:
        explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
        ~MainWindow();
        static MainWindow* GetInstance(QWidget* parent = 0);
signals:

public slots:
    void on_pushButton_3_clicked();
    void MainWindow_TextBrowser_String(const QString & newText);

private:
        Ui::MainWindow *ui;
        static MainWindow* mainInstance;

    };
```

Here is my mainwindow.cpp

```
    // Constructor
    MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
        QMainWindow(parent),
        ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
    {
        ui->setupUi(this);
    }

    // Destructor   
    MainWindow::~MainWindow()
    {
        delete ui;
    }

    void MainWindow::on_pushButton_3_clicked()
    {
        TestWindow mwindow;
        mwindow.start();
    }

    MainWindow* MainWindow::mainInstance = 0;

    MainWindow* MainWindow::GetInstance(QWidget *parent)
    {
        if (mainInstance == NULL)
        {
            mainInstance = new MainWindow(parent);
        }
        return mainInstance;
    }
void MainWindow::MainWindow_TextBrowser_String(const QString & newText)
{
    QString TextBrowser_String = QString(newText);
    ui->textBrowser->append(TextBrowser_String);

}
```

I create the testwindow object in the pushbutton send the start function to call the findchild window to send a string to the textbrowser window

Here is my testwindow.cpp

```
void testwindow::start()
{
        // Create a new mainwindow on the heap.
        MainWindow* instance = MainWindow::GetInstance();
        // Or I can call
        // MainWindow instance; then point to findchild
        QString Test_Window_String = QStringLiteral("Test Window String");
        instance->findChild<QTextBrowser*>("textBrowser")->append(Test_Window_String);
}
```

I understand that you can use a singal and slot and simply just create a signal that sends the string to the append textbrowser

```
void testwindow::singalandslot()
    {
           MainWindow* instance = MainWindow::GetInstance();
           connect(this, SIGNAL(TextBrowswer_String(const QString &)), instance , SLOT(MainWindow_TextBrowser_String(QString &)));
}
void testwindow::fireSignal()
{
    emit TextBrowswer_String("sender is sending to receiver.");
}
```

Even with a signal or FindChild it seems that the object is already deleted or i'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please share your Ui::MainWindow Class and setupUi implementation to get a clear view?

Hope you have created the instance for QTextBrowser* inside setupUi or in the constructor.

With the below setupUi implementation, both ur usecases are working.

```
namespace Ui
{
class MainWindow: public QWidget
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  QTextBrowser* textBrowser;
  void setupUi(QWidget* parent)
  {
    setParent(parent);
    textBrowser = new QTextBrowser(parent);
    textBrowser->setObjectName("textBrowser");
    textBrowser->setText("Hello");
  }
};
}
```

Comment: your creatin it within the mainwindow which i don't want it to do. As you can see in the source code. I am sending data from one class to the main class via findchild or signals..

Comment: You have 2 MainWindow  class right??? one Ui::MainWindow and ::MainWindow. i have provided implementation in Ui::MainWindow (i.e) wherever u have kept your QTextBrowser* instance , n assign ::MainWindow as a parent to textBrowser.

Comment: the Ui::mainwindow is the generated from reading UI file 'mainwindow.ui' so its just the normal one

Comment: Any help from anyone?